# How to make EC2 userdata script run in an open window that is visible when RDP into instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I provide a powershell script to an EC2 via userdata. I cannot see the script running, but know it's running because I can see things happening (files being created etc)

But if I want to actually see the script running (i.e. in a powershell window), how can I do this?

To be very explicit, suppose the userdata powershell script simply consisted of `TIMEOUT 3600`, then after launching the instance, I would want to be able to RDP into the instance and see the powershell window open and counting down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to see the script executing in a window. It is triggered by a utility called `EC2Launch` (or, for older versions of Windows, `EC2Config`).

You can, however, look at the **log files**.

From [Running Commands on Your Windows Instance at Launch - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-windows-user-data.html):

> Any scripts in the instance user data are executed during the initial launch of the instance. If the persist tag is found, user data execution is enabled for subsequent reboots or starts. The log files for `EC2Launch` and `EC2Config` contain the output from the standard output and standard error streams.
>
> With EC2Launch, the log file is:
>
> ```
> C:\ProgramData\Amazon\EC2-Windows\Launch\Log\UserdataExecution.log
> ```
>
> With EC2Config, the log file is:
>
> ```
> C:\Program Files\Amazon\Ec2ConfigService\Logs\Ec2Config.log
> ```

Comment: Thanks John, I did not know of this log file. If I open the log file while the script is trying to write to it, what will happen? Is there some hacky method I can use to achieve an actual powershell window along the lines of having the userdata script launch another script (in an actual window?) - it would be so much easier as I could pause execution etc too. But I guess this is a windows limitation?

Comment: A background service is running the script. Not a windowed environment.